# update status when date and time expire mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have table like this

```
+--------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
| id     | event_date| event_time   |status            |
+--------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
|  15145 | 2007-11-18|    10:00:00  |      1           |
|  15146 | 2007-11-16|    03:00:00  |      1           |
|  15148 | 2007-11-17|    10:00:00  |      1           |
|  15150 | 2007-11-14|    05:00:00  |      1           |
|  15314 | 2007-11-22|    10:00:00  |      1           |
|  15315 | 2007-11-23|    10:00:00  |      1           |
|  15316 | 2007-11-15|    10:00:00  |      1           |
+--------+-----------+--------------+------------------+
```

i want to updata the status to '0' when date and time expires...

i write a script for update status, that was an cronjob script this run in seconds based, when ever the date and time over i want update the status

```
include('../../config.php'); 

$createCon = new createCon; 

$get_all_events = mysqli_query($createCon->connect(),"SELECT * FROM gic_events");

$get_all_events_num = mysqli_num_rows($get_all_events);

if ($get_all_events_num > 0) {
    while ($sp_events = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_all_events)) {
        $date = date("Y-m-d");

        $event_id = $sp_events['event_id'];

        $event_date= $sp_events['event_date'];

        $event_time = $sp_events['event_time'];

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

        $time = date("h:i:s");

        $update_events = mysqli_query($createCon->connect(),"UPDATE gic_events SET event_status='0' WHERE DATE(event_date) < '$date' AND event_id='$event_id'");

        $num = mysqli_affected_rows($createCon->connect());

        if($update_events){
            echo "changed";
            echo "<br>";
        }
        else{
            echo "no changed";
            echo "<br>";
        }

    }
}
```

this work fine in date section means, when this script run in second based and update status to '0' . but i want to update status in date and time expire.

any idea ?

Comment: Why are you storing date and time in separate columns?  This will make checking for expiry much harder.  Instead, just use a single datetime column to record the date/time of each event.

Comment: because date is today date and time added from admin backend...